# jQuery: keypress() - timestamp

Tags: jquery, timestamp, keypress

currently I'm using jQuery and especially the function

```
keypress()
```

This function can tell me a lot about which key was pressed, where and WHEN.
But the WHEN is my problem:
So this code...

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
  alert(event.timeStamp);
});
```

... returns a number like 259669935 (in milliseconds).
Actually, 259669935 milliseconds are about 72.13 hours.

So how is this "timestamp" produced and how can I convert it into date+time?

**edit (solved):**

If `event.timeStamp` does not work on your system, just use...

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
```

...instead. New code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
  alert(new Date().getTime());
});
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This will convert it to a Date.

```
var date = new Date(timeStamp);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SyRtx/10/

Comment: 262763669 (produced before 5 minutes) = Sun Jan 04 1970 01:59:23 GMT+0100
That's definitely not today ;)

Comment: I just added an example on jsfiddle that works. The timestamp comes from what your browser thinks the system time is.

Comment: Ok, on jsfiddle the timestamp and the date are about the same as in my comment above. If all this depends on the system I'll find another solution, because I don't want to set all my hope in the users systems. Thanks for your answer.